# How to use superstatic with React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I want to use [superstatic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superstatic) with React to host my build files.

After running `npm run host` my files are builded and superstatic is started.

See code below.

package.json - in *'./application/dist'* are my build files

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "npm run lint && webpack --mode production",
    "host": "npm run build && superstatic ./application/dist --port 3000",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts,.tsx",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
  },
"devDependencies": {...},
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "superstatic": "^6.0.4"
  }
```

superstatic.json

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "*",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I get:**

When I open localhost:3000 I can see my application, but when the browser is refreshed I get "Cannot GET /*some_url* ".

**What I want:**

I expect to get content which is on /*some url*, but instead i get "Cannot GET /*some_url* ".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research I find out that [**superstatic**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superstatic) **don't** even **have** code for the `pushState`.

They mention `pushState` only in the README.md and as a keyword in the package.json file.

As you can see:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Use [**spa-http-server**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spa-http-server) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your `.htaccess` (or nginx.conf ).

Try:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>


  #######################################################################
  # GENERAL                                                             #
  #######################################################################

  # Make apache follow sym links to files
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  # If somebody opens a folder, hide all files from the resulting folder list
  IndexIgnore */*


  #######################################################################
  # REWRITING                                                           #
  #######################################################################

  # Enable rewriting
  RewriteEngine On

  # If its not HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

  # Comment out the RewriteCond above, and uncomment the RewriteCond below if you're using a load balancer (e.g. CloudFlare) for SSL
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

  # Redirect to the same URL with https://, ignoring all further rules if this one is in effect
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

  # If we get to here, it means we are on https://

  # If the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # and the directory with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # and we are not opening the root already (otherwise we get a redirect loop)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/$

  # Rewrite all requests to the root
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /

</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Do not cache sw.js, required for offline-first updates.
  <FilesMatch "sw\.js$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
  </FilesMatch>
```